# Ubuntu 15.04 install error. stuck in the third step.. please help

Tags: partitioning, 15.04

While trying to install ubuntu 15.04 in my dell laptop, I'm unable to go further steps after the step where we are prompted select the third party mp3 software....
The error is "the root file system is not defined. please correct this from partitioning menu".
I'm unable to go to the next step to select partitions and other options.
Please help..
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting the computer and disabling the check for enabling third party software then you can install it manually after installation via 'Sudo apt-get install rythmbox'

Answer (score 0):

When you select the partitioning scheme, Just opt for "Erase disk and install Ubuntu" (or something similar.  It will erase everything on disk and install ubuntu only).  That should automatically 'define' the root filesystem for you.  What it's really doing is assigning a mount point to your main partition where everything is stored.